# Lightweight NLP frameworks for Python

Tags: python, heroku, nlp, spacy

I'm using spaCy at the moment to determine the semantic similarity between two strings. It works well and only requires a couple of lines of code with all the legwork being done behind the scenes:

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en')
>>> nlp('string').similarity(nlp('another string'))
0.796
```

However it requires ~600mb of module data. As I'm hosting on Heroku this far exceeds the slug size available. I'm looking at other alternatives for hosting, but is there another framework I could use? I don't require the 'industrial-strength' of spacy, but other frameworks don't seem to work as well/aren't as quick to implement.

Comment: On [spaCy doc](https://spacy.io/docs/usage/), it shows an option to download only some of the language model. In your case, you may be interested in downloading just the vectors - through `python -m spacy.en.download glove`. If this alone cost you 600mb, then I'm not sure if there's any alternative for you, as most of this storage is taken up by vectors for nearly 13,000 vocabs stored in spaCy and any less data would lead to worse accuracy.

Comment: It works with the smaller parser model, but yes it's still around 600mb. I think for the time being I'll have to simply use fuzzy string comparison which obviously doesn't capture sentiment but it's better than nothing. I'll also look into hosting on a VPS.

Comment: Seems like you're only using the word vectors, why don't you switch to smaller embeddings size (default spacy glove are of 300 dimensions), also you might be able to use smaller vocabulary depending on your usage

Answer (score 2):

> spaCy models, as of v1.7.0, can be installed as Python packages. This
>   means that they're a component of your application, just like any
>   other module.

This was was recently introduced, 20th of March 2017, a 50 MB model:

> en_core_web_sm    50 MB   Vocab, syntax, entities, word vectors

You have more details in the webpage
https://spacy.io/docs/usage/models